# Point symbology drawing incorrectly in ArcGIS Online web map?

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-online, map-service

I have created a map service (via ArcGIS Server) to serve SDE content up to a web map/application in ArcGIS Online.  The service contains a group of 10 shapefiles (points, lines, and polygons).  All the data is present and the map service works correctly when opened in ArcMap.  However, whenever I add the service to an ArcGIS Online web map, the point symbols draw offset approximately 60 feet to the southwest (see picture).  Blue selection box is true point position; note the symbology to the SW.
[image: Blue selection box is true point position, note the symbology to the SW.]

Polygons and lines draw as they should.  If I add the individual shapefiles in the group to the map (rather than bringing in the whole service), the points draw fine.  Doing this, though, I lose the ability to group layers.  All data is in the same projection.

Any idea what's going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem was "solved" (really more of a workaround) by changing the projection/transformation of the **data frame** in the map service to Web Mercator (WGS84).  This allowed me to not have to reproject data that we have stored in a DBMS (via ArcSDE) and still symbolize the points correctly in my web app.